# rails 3.2 routes not matching :controller constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, constraints

I'm using the route:

```
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :constraints => {:id => /.*/, :controller => /[a-z]$/}
  match ':controller', :to => :index, :constraints => {:controller => /[a-z]/}
  get ':id' => 'user#show', :constraints => {:id => /.+/}
```

And when I run rake show routes:

```
 /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format) {:id=>/.*/}
 /:controller(.:format) :controller#index
 GET /:id(.:format)         user#show {:id=>/.+/}
```

The constraints on :controller are not shown.

My goal is to have a request for "M. Bovary" to route to '/user/show/', :id => 'M. Bovary'.  Currently it's routing to Mcontroller#index, with no id passed at all.  "/m" => "MController#index"

It seems to me that rails is matching the first part of the constraint then "throwing away" the rest of the argument. Constraints seem to ignore ^ or $ or \Z, so that's not an option.

Comment: I don't see where you think there is a bug. The rules match in order, so your first rule should match on a request to a URL like "/m". Is the route snippet complete? What do you call the "default" route here?

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean in that it's not matching the "m." controller and throwing an error.  But the constraints should make it fall through to the 2nd route, rather than letting there be some "unused" part of the request line.  Any way to add a $ terminator to not allow extra crap after :controller?

Comment: Your constraint currently only checks that the controller name has a letter in in. It can have one, or two, or letters and numbers. I can't understand what you're trying to do. Why don't you start explaining your requirements and a couple of sample URL's and how you desire to route them.

Comment: rails is probably assuming that the '. Bovary' part is the format (like .html, .json and so on)

Comment: You got it, add that as an answer so I can mark it please :)    match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :constraints => {:id => /.*/, :controller => /[a-z]$/, :format => /(html|js)/} works!

Comment: Frederick Cheung, could you add your comment as an answer please so I can mark you correct? :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frederick Cheung got the answer in comments above, but he wouldn't add it here so I am to close this old question.

Since the url has a "." in it, rails is confused that that's an extension.  Help it by specifying the format:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :constraints => {:id => /.*/,
 :controller => /[a-z]$/, :format => /(html|js)/}
```